# Webkit / Firefox alignment issue

Tags: wordpress, firefox, webkit, alignment, margin

I'm stumped here. I've got maybe 2-3 pixel difference with my header text (img) when displayed in FF vs an webkit browser. Not a whole lot going on in this page. Both the CSS and HTML validates. Doesn't appear to be and text zoom related.  What am I missing?

www.caribouhouse.com

Answer (score 1):

There's a hack for overwriting a css rule in firefox 3 , you can use this :

`.foo{}/* other browsers */

    .foo, x:-moz-any-link { } /* FireFox 2 */

    html>/**/body .foo, x:-moz-any-link, x:default { } /* Only FireFox 3 */`

Answer (score 0):

FF and WebKit use different methods/algorithms to render text. Even WebKit by itself uses more than one method to render text, depending. Because of kerning etc it's normal to see different implementations have a difference of a few pixels when rendering text, even when the text is the same font in both cases.

Comment: Well that's annoying. I figueed that to be the case though.

Comment: @Justin - It's a huge subject but there's a little more about it e.g. [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering.html) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html). For what it's worth, FireFox's rendering behaves more like the Windows O/S APIs, and less like Safari's.